# mutateIn to delete particular array element in couchbase

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase

[image: Array example.]

I have an array in my document in couchbase as shown above. I want to delete a particular element depending on its id by using mutateIn

Comment: There isn't a conditional `remove` that I know of (yet). You could change the modeling so that it's nested objects instead of an array. Then you could remove `products.home`, `products.school`, etc. Also, you might be able to do this with a N1QL `UPDATE` instead of a subdocument operation.